# Outlook rest api create reply draft error

Tags: outlook, outlook-restapi

I am trying to create draft reply message for outlook but i am getting an error 
{"error":{"code":"RequestBodyRead","message":"The parameter 'Comment' in the request payload is not a valid parameter for the operation 'CreateReply'."}}

I am sending the Comment parameter as json.

Comment: The `Comment` parameter is only present in the `beta` version of the API. Are you using that? What URL are you posting to?

Comment: Thanks Jason, yes i was using v2.0 instead of beta version of the api